# Copy formatted tabbed table trimmed in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

I have a text editor logbook and need to copy the contents into an Excel sheet.

Logbook content:

```
    01.01.2000
    ----------
    Entry One.\t\t\t\t\t8 Hours
    Entry Two.\t\t\t\t\t20 Minutes
```

If I paste this into Excel, the content `8 Hours` is miles away from the `Entry One.` Cell. How can I correctly copy this content so that I have only two cells by each other?

Excel goal example:

```
    |01.01.2000|          |
    |----------|          |
    |Entry One.|8 Hours   |
    |Entry Two.|20 Minutes|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paste, excel converts unquoted tabs into column breaks and unquoted line breaks into row breaks. This is why if you directly paste in content where a quote immediately follows (a) a line break, (b) a tab, or (c) the beginning of the file, your spreadsheet may not behave as expected.

To solve this, you'll want to replace all the extra tabs with a single tab. To do this, go into Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> on Windows). Type in `\t{2,}`<sup>†</sup> in the *Find* box and `\t` in the Replace box. Make sure *Search Mode* is set to *Regular expression* and press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

---

<sup>† `\t+` would work as well, but it'd be slower on very large files that actually have single spaces.</sup>

Comment: This actually solved my formatting problem. Thank you very much! But i cant find the _Regluar expression_ Mode in Excel 2010. Do you have an idea where i can find it? The Internet tells me to use VBA and Add-Ins, but i think thats not the way to go.

Comment: @Daniel Ahh, sorry, I should've clarified. I meant that it'd help to pre-process the data, so I gave instructions for Notepad++, since you had tagged your question with it.

Comment: Anyway, your way of pre-formatting ist pretty good and correct. I do know now, that the expensive Office Suite doesnt have a build-in function for regexes. Thanks for your answer!